# Fixed number rounding down in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, rounding, floor

### Problem

I get numbers from 1 to 5 including all possible floating point numbers in between. The output must contain two digits after comma and in case of after-comma digits they need to be rounded down (floor).

Example input and output:

- 1 -> 1.00
- 4.3 -> 4.30
- 1.1000 -> 1.10
- 1.5999 -> 1.59

### My Try

My try is doing a Math.floor on the 100x of the number and dividing afterwards to get rid of the unwanted digits after comma. The Number.toFixed(2) gets me the possibly missing zeros afterwards:

```
(Math.floor(input * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
```

The problem with this is JavaScript's floating point inprecision:

```
Math.floor(4.14 * 100) / 100
// results in 4.13 because 4.14 * 100 is 413.99999999999994
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript)

Comment: @DylanCorriveau I don't think it's the same, what Hubert wants is to preserve the 2 significant digits after the decimal without rounding up or down, the other question specifically talks about rounding

Comment: I think what you want can only be solved by string manipulation, rounding the numbers to get the 2 significant digits as you see them is finicky

Comment: That's because the number which prints as `4.14` is actually 4.13999999999999968025576890795491635799407958984375, see http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function formatNumber(x) {
  // convert it to a string
  var s = "" + x;
  // if x is integer, the point is missing, so add it
  if (s.indexOf(".") == -1) {
    s += ".";
  }
 // make sure if we have at least 2 decimals
  s += "00";
  // get the first 2 decimals
  return s.substring(0, s.indexOf(".") + 3);
}

document.write(1 + " -> " + formatNumber(1) + "<br/>");
document.write(4.3 + " -> " + formatNumber(4.3) + "<br/>");
document.write(1.1000 + " -> " + formatNumber(1.1000) + "<br/>");
document.write(1.5999 + " -> " + formatNumber(1.5999) + "<br/>");
document.write(4.14 + " -> " + formatNumber(4.14) + "<br/>");
```

Here is my attempt, the idea is documented in the code. Of course, there are probably better solutions, but this is a quick & dirty solution.

Comment: Looks like this problem really can be solved through string manipulation only. Great code!

Answer (score 0):

nowadays it's much simpler.

Use *Number.prototype.toFixed()*, but the value will round up.

- 1 -> 1.00
- 4.3 -> 4.30
- 1.1000 -> 1.10
- 1.5999 -> **1.60**

Here is official docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

```js
function financial(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}

document.write(1 + " -> " + financial(1) + "<br/>");
document.write(4.3 + " -> " + financial(4.3) + "<br/>");
document.write(1.1000 + " -> " + financial(1.1000) + "<br/>");
document.write(1.5999 + " -> " + financial(1.5999) + "<br/>");
document.write(4.14 + " -> " + financial(4.14) + "<br/>");
```